# Can you tell me where I went wrong with routing? and what I could do to correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Problem which my terminal shows when I try `rails server`!

```
  /home/<user_name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load': /home/salmanalam/rails_projects/blog/config/routes.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
      post GET /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show
```

This is my content of `config/routes.rb`

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  get "welcome/index"
  root 'welcome#index'
  post GET '/posts/:id(.:format)' 'posts#show'
```

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file

Comment: Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  get "welcome/index"
  root 'welcome#index'
  post GET '/posts/:id(.:format)' 'posts#show'

Comment: That does not look valid, can you edit your question and paste the content of your `config/routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some extraneous (non)code at the conclusion of your routes. The entirety of your `routes.rb` should read something like this, instead:

```
# config/routes.rb
Blog::Application.routes.draw do 
  resources :posts 
  get "welcome/index" 
  root "welcome#index"
end
```

First, you're missing the `end` declaration to your block. Then, the piece of your code that reads `post GET '/posts/:id(.:format)' 'posts#show'` is not actually a route, but part of the output if you ran `rake routes` from the command line. It says that there's a `show` route for the `Post` resource.

I'm not sure how it got in your code, but removing it should resolve the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this
namespace 'posts', :defaults => {:format => 'eg.json'} do
match '/posts/event/:id', :to=> "post#show", :method => :get
end

root :to=>"welcome#index"